# Django: can't read urlopen responses's file as binary

Tags: python-3.x, django

I have a problem with file requesting.

python 3.9.1, django 3.1.7

What i do:

`response = request.urlopen('some_good_address')`

> response.**class** == <class 'django.core.files.base.File'>
>
> response.file.**class** == <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>

After that i need to read response as binary:

`base64.b64encode(response.read())`

On 2.7 it was OK.

Error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: What is the specific error you're getting?

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte